# ffmpeg: SilenceRemove with a buffer

Tags: ffmpeg

[Silenceremove](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove) can sound a bit jarring because the edits are precisely at the start and end of the detected areas of silence. Is there a way to use a filter like below, to remove any silence spanning longer than 1000 milliseconds, but then buffering 100 milliseconds at the beginning and end to let the edit be less obtrusive?

`silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-90dB`